# Calculation of surface derivatives at the edge of the raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, slope

I was wondering how does ArcMap10.2 calculate surface derivatives (slope, aspect) at the edge of the raster, since the Horn algorithm is used and uses the 8 neighboring pixels around each pixel. When beyond the raster there are pixels with NoData, do they contribute in the calculation of slope, aspect etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the ArcGIS help says about [How Slope Works](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/How_Slope_works/009z000000vz000000/):

> *If there is a cell location in the neighborhood with a NoData z-value, the z-value of the center cell will be assigned to the
>   location. At the edge of the raster, at least three cells (outside the
>   raster's extent) will contain NoData as their z-values. These cells
>   will be assigned the center cell's z-value. The result is a flattening
>   of the 3 x 3 plane fitted to these edge cells, which usually leads to
>   a reduction in the slope.*

Most probably this is also valid for [Aspect](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/How_Aspect_works/009z000000vp000000/), though it's not clearly stated in the help page.